# WooCommerce hide coupon field , but not for logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, coupon

I try to get my coupon field hidden but I would like to keep it on for logged-in users.
On this code, it does not work.
What can be my solution?

```
function hide_coupon_field_on_cart( $enabled ) {
    if( !is_user_logged_in() )
          return $disabled;
    if ( is_cart() ) {
        $enabled = false;
    }
    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled', 'hide_coupon_field_on_cart' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hide_coupon_field_on_cart( $enabled ) {
    if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
          return false;
    }
    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled', 'hide_coupon_field_on_cart' );
```